# Net::HTTP adding port

Tags: ruby, uri, net-http

I am doing an HTTP GET request but need to be able to add the port as it is not 80. Here is my code:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://#{@hs_host}/dir/testpage.asp?event=#{CGI::escape(event_name)}"))
```

Which works perfect when the server is on port 80. What if the server is on port 85? Normally I would add :85 after the host but that seems to error.

Comment: 'that seems to error' what exactly means? What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uri = URI.parse(http://#{@hs_host}/dir/testpage.asp?event=#{CGI::escape(event_name)}")
uri.port = 8080
```

Or even:

```
uri = URI.parse(http://#{@hs_host}:8080/dir/testpage.asp?event=#{CGI::escape(event_name)}")
```

Comment: Ok not sure what I did wrong the first 50 times. But your second example is what I thought I was doing. It now works. Guess I must be slow this morning. Thank you.